# How do you get python to read a whole text file, not just one line?

Tags: python, text-files

I've been trying to get my code to search a text file for a product entered by the user but it only reads the first line, not the whole file as I want it to.

Here is my code:

```
 order=input("Please enter the name of the product you wish to purchase\n")
    myfile=open("barcode.txt","r")
    details=myfile.readlines() #reads the file and stores it as the variable 'details'
    for line in details:
        if order in line: #if the barcode is in the line it stores the line as 'productline'
            productline=line
            quantity=int(input("How much of the product do you wish to purchase?\n"))
            itemsplit=productline.split(' ') #seperates into different words
            price=float(itemsplit[1]) #the price is the second part of the line
            total=(price)*(quantity) #this works out the price
            print("Your total spent on this product is: " +'£'+str(total))
        else:
            break
```

Comment: You break from the loop if you can't find the order in the first line.

Comment: The reason you're getting only one line is because you immediately break

Comment: change it with `pass` or supress the else statement

Comment: remove `else: break`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your were breaking out of the loop:
(Btw i added a with statent for opening the file in a more pythonic way)

```
order = input("Please enter the name of the product you wish to purchase\n")
with open("barcode.txt","r") as myfile:
    details=myfile.readlines() #reads the file and stores it as the variable 'details'
    for line in details:
        if order in line: #if the barcode is in the line it stores the line as 'productline'
            productline=line
            quantity=int(input("How much of the product do you wish to purchase?\n"))
            itemsplit=productline.split(' ') #seperates into different words
            price=float(itemsplit[1]) #the price is the second part of the line
            total=(price)*(quantity) #this works out the price
            print("Your total spent on this product is: " +'£'+str(total))
```

Comment: When I run the code, I keep getting an error message saying the barcode.txt is not found

Comment: Have you created a file called `barcode.txt` in the same directory? (if not you need to create it)

Comment: I did, might just be my computer, it's been playing up recently.

Answer (score 3):

Your code would break out after the 1 line is checked.

You have

```
for line in details:
    if order in line:
        # Does stuff
    else:
        break
        # This breaks out of the `for line in details` loop.
```

So if the order is not in the first line, it exits the loop.

You are most likely looking for something akin to

```
for line in details:
    if order in line:
        # Do stuff
        break # You want to break if you found the order
    else:
        continue
```

Although in that case, the `else: continue` branch is not needed, as you are not planning on executing anything if the order is not found.

As an aside, files support iteration naturally, so you don't need to do the following

```
myfile = open("barcode.txt", "r")
details = myfile.readlines()
# this line ^ can be removed, and you can just iterate over the file object itself 
for line in myfile:
    # do stuff
```

Don't forget to close the file once you're done, with `myfile.close()`, or alternatively use a context manager like

```
with open("barcode.txt", "r") as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        # Do stuff
# Once you go out of the `with` context, the file is closed for you
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `break` to exit the loop too soon:

```
for line in details:
        if order in line:
            # do stuff
        else:
            break  #<-- this is exiting the loop
```

You want to use `pass`, as @whitefret said in the comments:

```
for line in details:
        if order in line:
            # do stuff
        else:
            pass #<--- this will continue the loop
```

Or you can just leave out `else` entirely:

```
for line in details:
        if order in line:
            # do stuff
```

Comment: I think `continue` is probably more in line with what the OP expected (although equally redundant in this particular case)

Answer (score 0):

For reading a file please check: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

```
fp = open(file_name)
print fp.read() # prints all data in file name
```

Few suggestions:

- Take all inputs at once. # nt like quantity=int(input("How much of t"
- Read all data at once.
- Once you got all variables, now start working on logic.
- you dont need to do "productline=line"
- if you dont need 'else', then dont use it.

Check for Zen of python, Python PEP8, and some programming standards and style.to make you code look cool.